# Recognize different types of client in a C client/server program

Tags: c, client-server

Should I implement a client / server program in C.
I know how to create a server and a client, but I don't know how to recognize different types of client.
Let me explain, I have a server S and I have two clients D and C, I wish that the server has a different behavior depending on the client that needs to be served.
How could I do?

Comment: Could the client send an initial message to the server saying what type of client they are?

Comment: If you need different behavior depending on client "type", the client needs to identify itself. If the difference in behavior is only because of different versions of the protocol, it might be enough with the protocol version number being transmitted, otherwise you might need to transmit more information.

Comment: @DermotBlair do you mean putting a simple write() that starts when a client connects?

Comment: Yes just some simple message that identifies the client. e.g. `Client Type: C` and then the server would know that it is client type C which is connecting and it could respond and behave appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I really understood your question, but i will answer what i'm thinking it is.
You can work with overloaded methods at your server program.
You make two methods with the same name and different arguments, each one with your respective identity of the client. For each one you make its behaviors.

Comment: I'm in C ,I can't use the overload